# Thread-safe UIKit methods

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to find out exactly what methods (names!) became thread safe in UIKit on iOS 4.0.

I've searched through Apple's docs with little success. For instance a `UIImage` created with imageNamed: is not safe to use on other threads (it will occasionally jettison its `CGImage` from the main thread), while `imageWithCGImage` might be(?). Also, I've seen claims that `UIColor` is safe to use on threads other than the main thread.

Is there some definite guide as to which methods are safe which ones isn't?

Edit:
What's interesting is UIKit classes that is interesting to use on separate threads, such as `UIImage`, `UIColor` etc.

Comment: how do you know UIImages's created with imageNamed: are not safe? Have you run into problems with it?

Comment: imageNamed: is not thread safe; see comment from an Apple developer here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/360659#360659

Answer (score 5):

From Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW1):

> *Note: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from `UIResponder` or that involve manipulating your application’s user interface in any way.*

Therefore, you really shouldn't be interacting with anything in `UIKit` on a background thread.

Comment: according to the iOS 4 release notes (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html): Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically:
• The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads.
• String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
• Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.