# How to update the UI in background thread without using mainthread

Tags: ios, multithreading, background

I am doing one application in which i got one HTML string in background thread. I want to load the `webview` using that HTML string *in background*.

If I load that web view on background, the app crashes. I don't want to load `webview` using main thread because *on that i don't want to disturb the main thread*. And i did the R&D in internet i got one possibility using GCD.I think that one also involved in main thread. SO please let me know how to update the UI in background.

Comment: UIKit will only work on main thread. Updating UIKit components from background thread will give unpredicted results, may also result in crash. In order to call function to update UI on main thread from background thread you can call `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` method.

Comment: Why would you not want to update the UI in the main thread?

Comment: ON that time main htreadis busy with another task

Comment: Main thread is for UI. If you have another task that isn't UI and is taking time it should be running on a background thread.

Comment: You have asked exactly what we say -- SHOULD NOT BE DONE
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10719424/667586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. UI must always be updated from the main thread. Whatever your reason for not wanting to do it from the main thread, that reason is invalid.

Comment: What about handlers in ios?Because in android they did this one using handlers.

Comment: Check this question if you need to update the UI on the main thread based on calculations done in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028185/android-thread-modify-edittext

Answer (score 0):

No. You cant update UI in other thread then main.

Comment: What about handlers in ios?Because in android they did this one using handlers