# UIKit and GCD thread-safety

Tags: ios, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

Many of the posts say that UIKit is totally not thread safe. Now on Apple documentation for GCD we can read that it's the DRAWING that is not thread safe. So would code like this be OK :

> > dispatch_async( ^{
> >
> > ```
> > //do some work
> > if(!self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController && )
> >     [self.window.rootViewController class] == anotherClass)
> >   {
> >       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  //do some work  });
> >   }
> > ```
> >
> > });

Comment: Well, considering rootViewController is declared as `@property(nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *rootViewController`, I would think not.

Comment: Why not just do the test in the dispatch, on the main thread. Messing with UI elements on threads other than the main one is playing with fire, and even if it works in iOS 6 your app may fail horribly in iOS 7...

Comment: Cause that block is in a while loop, which is in another dispatch_async(), otherwise that loop would block main thread.

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion is that what you have heard so far is misleading.

Here is a quote from Apple's [UIKit Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006955-CH1-SW1), credit to a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087068/thread-safe-uikit-methods):

> Note: For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an
>   application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes
>   derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your
>   application’s user interface in any way.

Also, note, that starting from iOS4, contrary to what you have assumed, according to [release notes found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html),

> Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. 
>   Specifically:
>
> - The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can    now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads.
> - String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
> - Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.

In fact furthermore in WWDC 2012 session "Building Concurrent User Interfaces", Apple engineer demonstrates drawing into *image graphics context* in a background thread.

My take-away:

- You can use multi-threaded drawing, but don't assume anything. Use only what is explicitly declared by Apple.
- Again, assume nothing. Don't touch any of the UIKit stuff that inherits from *UIResponder* from background thread.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you're not changing any values so yes,it's ok. Updating UI from background thread is not.

Comment: that is pretty much my question, a lot of people say that you should not touch UIKit at all from another thread, but then I read that it's the update, redraw, that is not thread safe, that is kind of confusing.

Comment: Read Apple guide on mutithreading, blocks and related stuff and you will get an idea how things are implemented under the hood. Then you'll seewhy it is safe to read or check values on non thread safe code and why it is not god idea to change or update values. UIKit is not an exception, it's just another non-thread safe collection of classes.